# Classic ASP - Understanding xsl if statement

Tags: xslt, asp-classic

Im trying to teach myself classic asp for a job that i have, and im going over some existing code, and i have come across a bit that i dont understand.

I was wondering if someone could explain the following line of code to me.

```
<xsl:if test="step/payment/options/renewal">
    <p class="note">Membership Renewal</p>
</xsl:if>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's VB? It looks like XML to me, or some form of XSLT.

Comment: Its in the HTML .. Ill update the question with a bigger block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting at the context node, it looks to see if anything can be found via the path `step/payment/options/renewal`, where each of these names attempts to select a child with the given name. If such a node is found, it outputs the `<p>` element to the result.